# Runtime error in Cyclic Binary String Question

Tags: data-structures

Today I am solving hackerrank problem and unfortunately, I am stuck on this. Actually, I passed 4 test cases but the rest test case shows runtime error..

---

**Here is my code -**

```
public static String leftrotate(String str, int d) {
        String ans = str.substring(d) + str.substring(0, d);
        return ans;
}

public static String rightrotate(String str, int d) {
    return leftrotate(str, str.length() - d);
}

public static int maximumPower(String s) {
    int size = s.length();
    int arr[] = new int[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(rightrotate(s, i), 2);
    }
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < size; j++){
            if(arr[i] % Math.pow(2, j) == 0){
                //System.out.println(arr[i] + "power = " +Math.pow(2, j));
                if(max < j){
                    max = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What means dividable by the largest power of 2?

```
xyz10000
```

is dividable by

```
   10000
```

So a 1 fby 0s. Otherwise it would not be dividable.

If there is no 1, the result is -1.

For rotatation equivalence, you are looking for the longest sequence of 0s which might be situated at front and tail of the sequence.

Now java's `BitSet` can juggle with bit operations, like find the next bit 1 from a given position.

To recap:

1. Look at the abstract problem, find the logic
2. Pick the data structure
3. Code it

Especially step 1 is very illuminating, yielding a very simple problem.
The key phrase being "the longest sequence of zeros."

I hope I did not spoil the coding.

Comment: This contest is ongoing in India and should not be discussed here.

Comment: Can you please delete this answer as you provided the answer to the question.

Comment: @AbhayGupta I cannot delete an accepted answer, and I thought I did leave much open for coding an answer, but I assume showing the way to an answer is a spoiler too, Especially as understanding the question seems to be the hard thing. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help @joop the only think I found to be difficult to understand is arbitrary large power ... But after your answer I got a clear understanding of everything that how I can count power of 2 by counting the number of consecutive 0s...  Before your comment I am diving every cyclic decimal number of the binary form by 2² and then print the highest power of 2 which is divisible .... Anyway you helped me a lot ... It is just a normal competition and my aim is to understand and solve as much as I can ...

Comment: Also I solved this question in O(n) time complexity

Comment: @NalinNishant happy with the feedback, saves my day.

Comment: Sorry it is a matter of liking math and CS puzzles / problem (solving) and abstracting from it; and then much coding: data structures and algorithms.